# Why doesn't object have an overload that accepts IFormatProvider?

Tags: c#, .net, object, globalization

When converting for instance a `decimal` to a `string`, you use the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and pass it as an `IFormatProvider`. But why is this overload not in `object`?

A nice implementation would be:

```
public virtual string ToString()
{
   // yadayada, usual ToString
}

public virtual string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
{
   return ToString();
}
```

This would cause no harm or benefit to the `object` class, but objects deriving from it can instead override the overload and it will be a lot easier to call it when you are unsure of the type.

The problem that made me run into this was when I was making a method that would be getting all properties of a class and writing it to xml. As I didn't want to check the type of the object, I just called `ToString`. But would this have been a decimal, the output would be based on the `CurrentCulture` of the thread, which is not optimal. The only workaround I can see is changing the `CurrentCulture` to `InvariantCulture` and then changing it back to whatever it was before. But that would just be ugly as I would have to write try finally blocks etc.

My current code is:

```
        foreach (var property in typeof(Order).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(c => ValidTypes.Contains(c.PropertyType)))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(order, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, 
                value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

But I would want it to be:

```
        foreach (var property in typeof(Order).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(c => ValidTypes.Contains(c.PropertyType)))
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(order, null);
            if (value != null)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, 
                value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            }
        }
```

Any benefit of not having this overload on `object`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to cast your `value` to `IFormattable`:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(Order).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
       Where(c => ValidTypes.Contains(c.PropertyType)))
{
    var value = property.GetValue(order, null);
    if (value != null)
    {
        var formattable = value as IFormattable;
        writer.WriteElementString(property.Name, 
        formattable == null ? value.ToString() : formattable.ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```

Comment: `IConvertible` actually makes more sense (unless you plan to format the number.)

Comment: @dlev: I disagree - the OP is specifically wanting *just* to format. Given that types may easily implement IFormattable but not IConvertible, and that the single method in IFormattable is exactly the one the OP wants to call, I think IFormattable makes more sense.

Comment: @Jon Based on OP's question, it looks like he has experience with actually using the `IConvertible` version of `ToString()`, which is why I mentioned it. Your point is well taken, though.

Answer (score 16):

Handy extension method of Peter's solution (modified to test also for IConvertible).

```
public static string ToInvariantString(this object obj)
{
    return obj is IConvertible ? ((IConvertible)obj).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        : obj is IFormattable ? ((IFormattable)obj).ToString(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        : obj.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try one of these:

```
string valueString = XmlConvert.ToString(value);
string valueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

XmlConvert.ToString() is made for XML, so it will keep things closer to the XML spec, such as using "true" instead of "True". However, it is also more brittle than Convert.ToString(). For example, this will throw an exception because of the UTC time:

```
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

but this works:

```
XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow, "o")
```

Comment: Convert.ToString actually casts to IConvertible and IFormattable (see previous posts):

    public static string ToString(Object value, IFormatProvider provider) { 
            IConvertible ic = value as IConvertible; 
            if (ic != null)
                return ic.ToString(provider); 
            IFormattable formattable = value as IFormattable;
            if (formattable != null)
                return formattable.ToString(null, provider);
            return value == null? String.Empty: value.ToString(); 
        }